# Installing Embedded RTOS in VMware

Tags: embedded, rtos

can RTOS like Nucleus and Zephr be installed in VMware

Is it possible to install in VMware. I like to learn RTOS and if there is any smaller version of some RTOS that can be easy to learn then that will be great. and do They have image file like ISO or do I need to compile the code with make?

System info Model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit Architecture: x86_64.

Comment: I doubt that the EE stack exchange would be the best place to ask for this. Have you tried already other sections?

Answer (score 0):

Some RTOSes have ports to platforms that are emulated by PC visualizers like VMWare, which mostly means x86 and arm.

People use Qemu, for example, all over the place to test their operating systems (qemu emulates way more platforms than just x86 and arm, and it's less optimized for PC emulation than VMware). Many RTOSes have a mode where you compile them as normal userland process for your normal operating system (ChibiOS definitely does, for example) - which probably makes more sense as it allows for a vastly reduced complexity and better isolated state than trying to run an operating system on a fully virtual CPU.

So, your question can be answered with "yes, please check the platforms your rtos of interest can run on."

Comment: if I use Qemu as emulator. can I install Nucleus RTOS in Qemu? if yes then is there a iso image that can be found on internet for Nucleus?

Comment: Last sentence. Please check which platforms your rtos is ported to. You can do that yourself. Compare these platforms with the platforms qemu emulates.

Comment: I will go with `ChibiOS` is it compatible with debian arm intel machine? I have specified system in question.  `Many RTOSes have a mode where you compile them as normal userland process for your normal operating system (ChibiOS definitely does, for example) - which probably makes more sense as it allows for a vastly reduced complexity` does this mean its a userspace application ?

Comment: `I will go with ChibiOS` Or Arduino

Comment: Arduino isn't even an RTOS... 666, really, please do your own research in a bit more depth.